# How to find the last element in the singly linked list?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

In a singly linked list, we know that the next of the last node point to the `null`, so that we can find it out by traversing.

If the last node of the singly linked list point to some middle node then how can we find the last node?

Comment: The question is unclear. If you are interested in loop-detection: lookup Floyd's algorithm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the "last node" points to some other node, then it isn't really the last node, is it? Not to mention this would stretch and possibly break the commonly accepted definiton of a "list".

Normally to find the last element you would do something like

```
Node *current = list.start,
     *next = current.next;

while (next != null)
{
    current = next;
    next = current.next;
}

print("Last node is " + current->value);
```

However, this assumes that your "last node" does actually point to null. Otherwise you will get stuck in an infinite loop.

It's generally good practice to keep a pointer the last node of a list as well as the first, so that's a trivial solution that doesn't depend on the last node pointing to null.

Comment: I believe this code works under assumption of list.start != nullptr.(Not empty list)
If given start is nullptr, line. 2 will cause error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess putting a "is_visited" boolean to nodes will satisfy just fine:

```
//make sure the counters of all nodes are 0
cur=head_node
cur->visit=1
while( cur->next!=null AND cur->next->visit==0) {
  cur=cur->next
  cur->visit=1
}
//cur points to the last node
```

Comment: I will not change the structure of the node, since i have data stored in it. And also i have above 50000 nodes in linked list.

Comment: @Raaga Then you will have to iterate through the list for every node, won't you? Worst case O(N^2). It's your call

Answer (score 0):

Even in a Singly Linked list you may use a Tail pointer. Still it'll be a Singly linked list, but it avoids `O(n=1)` in finding last node.

Answer (score 0):

Simple just traverse and fulfil the last condition of pointing to the null

```
void printlast(Node* n){
    while(n!=NULL){
        n=n->next;
        if(n->next==NULL){
            cout<<n->data<<" ";
        }
    }
}
```